# How to setup a day of week for reset Heroic instances?

Tags: azerothcore

The problem with changing the day of the week to reload heroic instances.
It's always Friday at 04:00.

I am trying to put in the config in the line:
**Instance.ResetTimeRelativeTimestamp =** 
one of the other dates:
**1552867201** = 18.03.2019 00:01 Monday
**1552953600** = 19.03.2019 00:00 Tuesday
**1553040001** = 20.03.2019 00:01 Wednesday
**1552521601** = 14.03.2019 00:00 Thursday
**1552608001** = 15.03.2019 00:01 Friday
**1552694401** = 16.03.2019 00:01 Saturday
**1552780801** = 17.03.2019 00:01 Sunday

Then I've cleared 3 tables in characters DB:
**instance_reset

character_instance

instance**

When I start the server - I see the same result - restart on Friday at 4:00.

Question: How to change the day of week? It must be Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just finished figuring this out myself. After much digging through the AzerothCore source, and it looks like the day of the week that instances are reset is chosen the *very* first time the server is started. As far as I can tell, `ResetTimeRelativeTimestamp` is not used to determine reset times. To be more specific:

- The server starts up and starts to load instance reset times from the `characters`.`instance_reset` table
- If an instance is missing an entry in the `instance_reset` table, an entry is added using the following formula:

  - Reset time = `today`(in UTC, rounded to nearest day) + `RaidDuration`(from mapdifficulty_dbc, named resetTime in code) + `Instance.ResetTimeHour`(from worldserver.conf)
  - Let's run through an example

    - You're in the US Central time zone, which is currently UTC-5. It's `2020_10_18 14:56:23`, Convert that to UTC and you get: `2020_10_18 19:56:23`. Round to the nearest day and you get `UTC 2020_10_18 00:00:00`
    - Let's say it's setting the reset time for ICC 10 man. If you look in [`mapdifficulty_dbc`](https://wow.tools/dbc/?dbc=mapdifficulty&build=3.3.5.12340#page=1), `RaidDuration` is `604800` seconds, which is 7 days.
    - Let's say you have `Instance.ResetTimeHour` set to the default value, `4`. This becomes `4 hours`.
    - Plug this all in and you get `resettime = 'UTC 2020_10_18 00:00:00' + 7 days + 4 hours = UTC 2020_10_25 04:00:00`, a Sunday. Convert back to US Central time and you get: `2020_10_24 23:00:00 CST`, a Saturday. Instances will reset on Saturday
- The next time the instance is reset, its next reset time is reset using `previous reset time + RaidDuration`.

#### This means that if you want to choose the day of the week, you need to do one of the following:

- Modify the instance reset times in the `instance_reset` table to be on the day of the week that you want. This approach is risky as it involves manipulating the reset timestamps in the DB directly
- Empty the instance table, then start the server on the day you want instances to reset. Yes, this still involves DB manipulation, but at least the contents of the table are generated by Azeroth Core instead of yourself.

#### Here's what I did to solve the issue

**The reason I've buried this so deeply in the answer is that you have to understand what you're doing before you start wiping out tables in your database. PROCEED WITH CAUTION.**

1. Shut down the worldserver
2. Empty the `characters`.`instance_reset` table via SQL
3. Set your system time to some time *before the current time* that *when converted to UTC* falls on the day of the week you'd like instances to reset
4. Start the worldserver. Wait for it to load. Login and confirm that instance lockouts are expiring at the correct time.
5. Shut down the worldserver
6. Set your system time back to the correct time and start the server back up again